# How to call method with Object... as parameter

Tags: java

I wonder how can I call a class method which are expecting Object...(Object[])
as parameter.

I can't know at compilation time now many parameters I need to pass to it,
so I can't do like `somemethod(1,2,3,4,5)`.

I'm doing big construction like:

```
if (param.lengts()==5) {
somemethod(1,2,3,4,5);
} elseif (param.lengts()==4) 
somemethod(1,2,3,4);
....
```

I was trying to pass `List<>` and `ArrayList<>` but without success.
Is there a simple way how to convert my dynamic array to the method? I can't change method constructor.

Problem about to call the method, not with declare or read parameters inside the method.

Comment: How is `somemethod` declared?

Comment: what is a "method constructor"? --- The easiest way would probably to overload the method with all eight primitives: `someMethod(boolean...)`, `someMethod(byte...)`, ... ,`someMethod(double....)`, `someMethod(Object...)`.

Comment: He probably means that he can't change the method definition.

Comment: somemethod deslare as :
public PrinterDocument(IPrintable... printables) {
       //
    }

Comment: You are dealing with a constructor, not a method. You need to pass instances of `IPrintable` instead of integers when calling that constructor.

Comment: it was just an exemble with integers.
I dont know how many IPrintable i need to pass on compiling time so i cant do  PrinterDocument(IPrintable1,IPrintable2,IPrintable3) or
PrinterDocument(IPrintable1,IPrintable2) because i dont know it. i Have ArrayList<IPrintable> and i need to make a call
PrinterDocument(IPrintable1,IPrintable2....ArrayList<IPrintable>.length())

Comment: Please define `param`, and what did you try to pass a `List` and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variable arguments for this:

```
private void somemethod(Integer.. array) {
}
```

And call it like this:

```
somemethod()    
somemethod(1)    
somemethod(1,2)
```

If you have an arraylist as an input, you can pass it as this:

```
someMethod(list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
```

Comment: This was not about this. Lets say i have input=ArrayList<integer> as input and i need  to call like: somemethod(input[0],input[1],input[2]...input[input.length()-1])

Comment: Convert the list to an array using the toArray method of the list.

Comment: Andrew check my updated answer, as suggested by @Jonathan as well

Comment: I guest this is the one i was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pass an array.

```
Object[] params = ... build the array from the args 
somemethod(params);
...
void somemethod(Object... objs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use var args:

method declaration:

```
void somemethod(Object ...){ }
```

And call this methodo with how many parameters you need.